# In Python, why do 'writer' is considered to be as an unexpected keyword argument for save

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I would like to save an animation using the function save in Python. During compilation, I get the following message:

```
anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer="ffmpeg")
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'writer'
```

Please note that I have installed successfully FFmpeg. Here is a minimal working environment:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from numpy import pi

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2),np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2) )  
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
Q = ax.quiver( X, Y, U, V, pivot='mid', color='r', units='inches')

ax.set_xlim(0, 2*pi)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2*pi)

def update_quiver(num, Q, X, Y):
    U = np.cos(X + num*0.1)
    V = np.sin(Y + num*0.1)
    Q.set_UVC(U,V)
    return Q,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, fargs=(Q, X, Y),
    interval=10, blit=False)

anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer="ffmpeg")
```

Comment: Find the *documentation* for the "anim.save" method (after identifying the type of object "anim"). What does it say?

Comment: @user2864740 Okay, I will see.

Comment: @user2864740 I spent the whole day looking for a good answer for this question but without any results!! Could you possibly suggest something that would push me a bit toward the right solution? Thank you

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save - appears to be the relevant documentation; if "anim" really is an Animation. But, hmm, that clearly lists the `writer` keyword argument. (Was there a change between versions?)

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Thank you. I executed the program you mentioned but I get the following message `FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg'] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writers'`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @BrianCain How can I know that? could you possibly tell me how?

Comment: look at `matplotlib.__version__`.

Comment: @BrianCain yes I found how! sorry it is 1.1.0

Comment: @BrianCain It seems to be old! I think that I need a newer one!!

Comment: @BrianCain Thank you very very very much!! It works!! The problem was indeed in the version of matplotlib!! You are a genius!! Thank you!! I can't believe it!! I spend difficult moments with this problem and now all is working very well !! Thank you!! you are the best!!! :)